# Change base HTTP requested directory -- CPanel

Tags: php, http, redirect, cpanel

I have a php websites hosted on a server. I use CPanel to manage it. public_html has lets say following directory structure

```
public_html
  - dir1
  - dir2
  - dir3
  - ....other files.....
  - website2home
```

Now I am trying to make **website2home** as the base directory of my website, but files inside **website2home** use some files from public_html folder and some files from within itself.

**THE PROBLEM**

When I assign a domain name to **website2home**, It does not reads the files from `public_html` folder (in fact, public_html folder is not visible) and shows some php warnings and some 404 not found errors. But lets say the domain name for original website is `www.aaa.com`, then if I access `website2home` by using `www.aaa.com/website2home` all works fine.

**So My Question...**

Is there any way to set the base directory, so that my **website2home** fetches all files and correct files without replacing hundreds of filepaths in php code?

Please answer considering that I don't want to modify source files of website.

Comment: What kind of files? css/js/images .. or `include "somefile.php"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for some kind of .htaccess configuration. For instance, you may set your *website2home* folder as base folder for your *www.aaa.com* domain and then redirect some file access to other folders using .htaccess, something like this..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule captcha.jpg ../captcha.jpg
RewriteRule \.pdf$ ../pdf_files/$1
```

Have a look to [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Edit: If, for some reason, the ../ redirection doesn't work, you always can redirect all your files to a pseudo-index PHP page. For instance:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule captcha.jpg my_index.php?access=../captcha.jpg
RewriteRule \.pdf$ my_index.php?access=../pdf_files/$1
```

And then, in your index PHP page you can simply load your PHP files in other folder:

```
require "../pdf_files/$requested";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that wont work as ../ directory is not visible.

Comment: Well, it is working on my production system, but perhaps it depends on some config systems that I don't know. Anyway, I have edited the answer to include a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: great thats working. But I don't know how? I have a very basic knowledge of this stuff, perhaps I need some coaching... But thanks for help, it solved the problem for now